# Why is this obvious scam asking me for interest first instead of asking for money?

Tags: scams

I got this email today:

> I hope you are doing great?
>
> This is X from Toronto-Canada. I have a lucrative business offer that will benefit us both immensely within a very short period of time.
>   However, I need your initial approval of interest prior to further and complete details regarding the deal.
>
> Thanks,
>   X.

It's not the first I receive. It's odd. No phishing (yet), no data request. Just asking for a reply. Is it the sole act of replying a threat to me? (not that I plan to do it) If so, how?

Comment: There's not nearly enough information here to identify what's going to come. At this point they're just sending out thousands of generic emails to see who self-selects by responding with interest.

Comment: @glibdud Sure, but why would that be the case? Speculation is fine in my opinion.

Comment: Because the people who respond are self-selecting to show they are credulous.

Comment: I would mark it as spam and ignore it.

Answer (score 3):

It's the starting of a scam. Once they see you have replied, your email is kept in seperate list. Over the period once you reply you could give some real details... But may get out when asked for money etc ...

However they would now have enough details that they would send a fresh email from different ID that is specifically addressed to you and show you some investment opportunity or some other scam. As this is more specifically addressed, one tends to drop his guard and get trapped in the scam

Comment: Thanks. I had the impression that, by "expressing interesting", they could use that to involve you in some form of scam which can then be used against you (for instance, changing the content of the email you sent). But I guess that's not really possible.

Comment: @luchonacho email is the easiest thing in the world to fake.  If they wanted to fake an email from you, they don't need you to send them one first to work with.